# Perl `send` pitfall with "connected" UDP `IO::Socket::INET`, ignoring destination address?

Tags: perl, sockets, udp, connection

I'm debugging some odd issue when a packet sent via an INET UDP socket is **not** sent to the given destination address.

The documentation (`perldoc -f send`) says:

> On unconnected sockets, you must specify a destination to send to, in which case it does a sendto(2) syscall.

That's all it says about the `TO` parameter an connected sockets.

However after hours of debugging it seems what the manual does *not* say is:

> On connected sockets the TO parameter is being ignored.

So I'd like to know:

- Are UDP sockets ever *connected*?
- Is my finding correct that the TO parameter for `send` is being ignored when `PeerAddr` was specified when creating a `IO::Socket::INET` (thus "connecting" the socket)?
- Shouldn't send return an error when the socket is "connected" and a destination address is specified, or is the implementation faulty (i.e.: Shouldn't a given destination override the socket's peer address when sending)? At least that would follow the principle of least surprise.

### A kind of an example

As it was requested to provide an example, here is one:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Socket;

sub _socket(;$$)
{
    my ($l, $p) = @_;
    my %params = ('Proto' => 'udp');

    @params{'LocalAddr', 'LocalPort'} = split(/:/, $l)
        if ($l);
    @params{'PeerAddr', 'PeerPort'} = split(/:/, $p)
        if ($p);
    return IO::Socket::INET->new(%params);
}

my $sock1 = _socket('localhost:1514');
my $sock2 = _socket('localhost:0', 'localhost:1514');
my $pkt;

while (defined(my $peer = $sock1->recv($pkt, 1000, 0))) {
    print "received $pkt\n";
    $sock2->send("response " . $pkt, 0, $peer);
}
```

Run it, and on the same host try `netcat -u localhost 1514`.
Then enter one line like "junk", and you'll see that the sample program does not send back to the sender, but to itself, causing a loop.

Running the example under `strace`, I see that `connect()` is being used to "connect" `$sock2`.

Comment: *"Are UDP sockets ever connected?"* -   if `connect` is called on a UDP socket it gets connected. It will only send packets to this address and only receive from this.

Comment: At the C level, even if a default destination address is associated with a UDP socket, it can be overridden using `sendto()` and an explicit destination.

Comment: (well, either that or it's an error; POSIX allows either behavior)

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful; simple client that shows how you create and use the socket, maybe a server side too.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Connecting with a connection-less protocol (UDP) is an interesting concept.

Comment: @Shawn The original code is 9756 lines distributed in 35 packages; it's a bit hard to make a mininal example from it. If I find time, I'll try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See your system's man pages for details on systems calls such as `connect` and `send`.

[On POSIX systems](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/connect.html), `connect` says

> For `SOCK_DGRAM` sockets, the peer address identifies where all datagrams are sent on subsequent `send()` functions, and limits the remote sender for subsequent `recv()` functions.

So using `connect` overrides any destination address you might provide elsewhere.

---

> Shouldn't send return an error when the socket is "connected" and a destination address is specified

The [docs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sendto.html) indicate error `EISCONN` "may or may not be returned for connection mode sockets" when "a destination address was specified and the socket is already connected."

Now, it's not clear to me what makes a socket a "connection mode socket", but it appears to be based on protocol. But given an apparent lack of other guidance for connected UDP sockets, I find it reasonable to expect the same behaviour as for protocols like TCP. That is, the address is ignored or error `EISCONN` is returned.

Comment: But there is a difference between `socket` and `connect` calls, and the perldoc does not state that `socket` calls `connect`. The `connect(2)´ man page also states: "*If the socket sockfd is of type SOCK_DGRAM, then addr is the address to which datagrams are sent by default, and the only  address  from  which datagrams  are  received.*" IMHO "default" does not say that it cannot be overridden.

Comment: @U. Windl, You can look at the source, but that is the system call to connect a socket. // I can't explain why it says "by default". That's clearly not what POSIX says. And as you noticed, it's clearly not what it does.

Comment: Still I think the documentation for Perl's `send` should be improved, and preferably when trying to use a "connected" socket with a `send` call that provides a destination, too, an error should  be triggered (rather than sending the packet to an address different from the given destination).