# How to select the "correct" socket to send datagram responses?

Tags: perl, sockets, routes, datagram

I have some Perl code that listens on an array of sockets via `select` for a request, and then some other routine sends out a response after significant processing.

Now the question is (assuming I have the peer's address in `$dest`):
How should I select the "correct" socket to use for sending the response to `$dest`?

Should I blindly use the socket where the request was received on, or should I try to duplicate routing logic to find the "best" socket, considering the address each socket is bound to, comparing it with `$dest` somehow?

I have little ideas how to do the latter, unfortunately.

I forgot one special case (that actually triggered the problem in the existing code):

It is possible that the array of listening sockets is reduced by the socket that received the request before the response can be set;
thus it seems I need to implement the second alternative.

Comment: Why do you have more than one UDP socket?

Comment: For the same reason as a web server may listen to multiple addresses. In fact addresses (sockets) can be added and removed dynamically.

Comment: I think you're saying it's because each is bound (using `bind`) to a different network adapter? (i.e. you used `bind`, and you didn't bind to `IPADDR_ANY`.) If so, you'll need to use the same socket you previously used because you can't use your loopback adapter to talk to the internet and you can't use your wifi adapter to talk to the loopback. But seeing that I don't think your normal web server actually does that, I'm not sure this is what you actually mean.

Comment: In short, you need to use the same socket if you have multiple sockets, but you probably shouldn't have multiple sockets when using UDP. Maybe you could show how you created the socket?

Comment: Just use the socket that received a packet to send the reply.

Comment: @Shawn You missed the last paragraph saying "*It is possible that the array of listening sockets is reduced by the socket that received the request before the response can be set*(...)"

Comment: @ikegami The code is very much like that in https://stackoverflow.com/q/72361970/6607497 without the peer being set.

Comment: That code only has one socket for the server ($sock1) and one socket for the client ($sock2). (The program happens to talk to itself.) You said you had a server with many sockets.

Comment: @ikegami I don't want to nit-pick, but you were asking: "*Maybe you could show how you created the socket?*" - I guessed you could imagine that code running in a `foreach` loop to fill an array of sockets.

Comment: That code wouldn't work in a loop. The socket creation would fail.

Comment: @ikegami Can you explain? That example creates two sockets using the `_socket()` subroutine. What makes you think it cannot be used to create more sockets?

Comment: You can't bind two sockets to the same port. So I ask again, please show how you create the sockets. Because, as it stands, every indication is that you are doing things quite incorrectly.

Comment: The original program is huge and complex; however why can't I have sockets in an array that bind like this?: ['localhost:1234', 'hostname:1234', 'hostname:12345'] (just for example) And back to the original problem: Assuming I received a request on 'hostname:1234' to remove that socket from the array, on which socket should the respose be sent, confirming that the socket was removed?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same socket for all communication with a given peer.

There are times where it doesn't matter, but there are times that it does.

---

That said, you probably should only have socket.

When you receive from a UDP socket, you are give the the address and port from which the socket originated.<sup>[1]</sup> This allows one socket to communicate with many other sockets.

For example,

Say the server S's socket is 0.0.0.0:1111 and one of its IP addresses is 1.1.1.1.

Say client A's socket is 0.0.0.0:2222 and say it uses IP address 2.2.2.2 to reach 1.1.1.1.

Say client B's socket is 0.0.0.0:3333 and say it uses IP address 3.3.3.3 to reach 1.1.1.1.

When the server calls `recv`, it will return either 2.2.2.2:2222 or 3.3.3.3:3333 (in a "packed" form) depending on whether A or B sent the message. This allows the server to know who is communicating with it, and what address to use when replying.

In the TCP world, the server might keep per-connection data in a hash keyed by client socket (the socket returned by `accept`). But in the UDP world, a similar server could keep per-connection data in a hash keyed by the string returned by `recv`.

This illustrates one reason why it's important to always use the same socket to send and receive message. If you start sending from different sockets, this hash lookup would fail.

---

There is one situation in which you'd want multiple sockets, and that's when you want to listen to some but not all network interfaces. For example, you might want to listen to the loopback adapter (127.0.0.1) and the virtual adapter used for communicating with a VM (x.x.x.x), but not to the wifi adapter (y.y.y.y) or the ethernet adapter (z.z.z.z)

A socket can either listen to all interfaces (by being bound to IPADDR_ANY (0.0.0.0), which is the default), or one interface. So listening (only) two interfaces requires having one socket bound to one of the interfaces (127.0.0.1) and another socket bound to the other (x.x.x.x).

Here, it's critical that you use the correct socket. Messages sent from the socket bound to the loopback adapter won't reach the VM, and messages sent from the socket bound to the VM's adapter won't reach the loopback adapter.

---

1. Well, you get the address and the port the packet provided as the originating address and port.

Comment: So will it work if I bind a socket to maybe `localhost:12345` and then try to use that socket to send to `192.168.123.123`? Will the kernel route the packet to the correct interface then? Specifically, I *don't* want a "wildcard bind" like `0.0.0.0:0` for the listening socket.

Comment: "*the string returned by recv*" is the *peer address*, right? Also I don't understand why I cannot use a "matching" socket to reach out corresponding clients via datagram.

Comment: Re "So will it work if I bind a socket to maybe localhost:12345 and then try to use that socket to send to 192.168.123.123?", You definitely can't receive from 192.168.123.123, but I would expect that you can't send to 192.168.123.123 either.

Comment: Re "*"the string returned by recv" is the peer address, right?*", It's the source address. For UDP, that's a combination of the IPv4/IPv6 address and the UDP port. A UDP socket could be said to have a peer if it's connected. If the socket has a peer, it will be the peer address. (In technical terms, if the socket is connected, the string returned will match the combination of PeerAddr and PeerPort passed to `connect`.)

Comment: Re "*I don't understand why I cannot use a "matching" socket to reach out corresponding clients via datagram.*", If you have matching sockets, you're doing something wrong. They should be replaced with a single socket.